# Ensure a service is finished before closing App (without retry)

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I am developing an application which a service that makes three requests to my backend and I need to ensure that requests are finished before close app.

I read about use `START_STICKY` on `onStartCommand` method but this option makes the service to retry causing repeated requests if, for example, app is closed when service have maked first request only:

- Run service...

  - Make request 1
  - Close APP
- Retry service by `START_STICKY` config ...

  - Make request 1 (repeated)
  - Make request 2
  - Make request 3

Is there any other way to ensure that the service finishes its execution before closing?

Comment: Do you have two services (main and retry)?

Comment: `WorkManager` will be your best friend dude.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that your want your task to be reliable and send the data to server but time doesn't matter that much(as you said you can retry so specific time not matter)

For this particulate requirement you get Android's latest `WorkManager`

When you hand a task request to `WorkManager` then it run based on when the work's conditions (like network availability and power) are satisfied, it make sure that your task get done in certain time interval.

According [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) and also a complete step by step guide about `WorkManager`

> WorkManager is intended for tasks that are deferrable—that is, not
> required to run immediately—and required to run reliably even if the
> app exits or the device restarts.
> For example:
>
> Sending logs or analytics to backend services Periodically syncing
>
> application data with a server

Please check this doc and follow the guide to learn more about it

Comment: Thanks, it looks great.